# Can't save picture in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to upload data to my database including an image. everything except the image works just fine.

I'm using a `FileUpload` component:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="ImgFileUpload" />
```

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ImgFileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        int length = ImgFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] pic = new byte[length];

        ImgFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GAMINGSYSTEMS;Initial Catalog=MAIN;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Personal " + "(Name, Job, Email, Picture) values (@Name, @Job, @Email, @Img)", conn);
            conn.Open();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtboxName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", txtboxEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtboxEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", pic);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My SQL Server database: since everything except the picture works ill just tell about the Image row in the table:

```
Column Name: Picture .  Data Type: image  .   Allow Nulls: Allowed.
```

When I try to upload an image all i get in the table at the picture is this (  )

what is the problem since I can't upload an image

Comment: It's usually a much better idea to store images in the file system, then store the path to the image in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have a link that explain your suggestion

Comment: Images are stores in form of `Bytes` in `Database`. So you can't see image in your database.

Comment: I know I cant see the picture in the database, but i sould be able to store it and then call it on my website

Comment: It is not always a much better idea to store images in the file system. Sometimes images are so so small (e.g. avatars) that storing them as VARBINARY(MAX) makes more sense. You won't have to think about the backup strategy or that the links can break if the files are moved elsewhere. FileTables solve that issue, but again for small projects that is an overkill.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to reset seek position as described [here](http://benwong.me/how-to-use-asp-net-fileuploads-postedfile-inputstream/) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1363129.aspx). Your code may look like this:

```
int length = ImgFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] pic = new byte[length];
ImgFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

ImgFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to change your column data type to long text.

After that convert your array of bytes in a base64 string

```
String imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(pic);
```

Optionally you can add "data:image/png;base64," before your base64String so it could be directly use in html5.

```
imageString = "data:image/png;base64," + imageString;
```

Comment: Why would you recommend long text?

Comment: A VARBINARY(MAX) column would make much more sense, given that an image is nothing but a chunk of binary data. The type is also better stored, if ever required, in a separate column.

Comment: I thought it could be helpful takes advantages of full-text search. Actually i did  take a look a this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx and it seems that doesn't matter if your data type is text or Byte[].

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar scenario like you before.

For my database, ( I'm using Microsoft Access 2010 ) For the image column, all my images are paths ~Images2/picture1.jpg . Images2 would be the folder to store all the pictures.

For VS Pro 2013 - Grid View Details view etc, I would link to the database and add an Imagefield column and replace the previous column (Boundfield) It will display the image.

For fileupload, this is the code I use which you can use for references. If you want to store the file link to ur database and then retrieve image to display in your website/app, you just alter the file save as "~Images2/picture1.jpg" and then retrieve with gridview etc. Hope it help you.

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile);
        }
        else
        {
            Label4.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload";
        }
    }
    void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile File)
    {
        string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images2/");
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        string pathToCheck = savePath + fileName;
        string tempFileName = "";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
        {
            int counter = 2;
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
            {
                tempFileName = counter.ToString() + fileName;
                pathToCheck = savePath + tempFileName;
                counter++;
            }

            fileName = tempFileName;

            // notify user that file name was changed
            Label4.Text = "A file name with the same name already exist, " +
                "<br />Your file was saved as " + fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            labelFileName.Text = fileName;
            LabelFileType.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
            LabelFileContentLength.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString();
            Label4.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully";
        }

        // Append the name of the file to upload to the path
        savePath += fileName;

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

    }
}
```